# Microfrontend framework for integrating react apps into an already developed monolith

Tags: reactjs, microservices, web-frontend, micro-frontend

My team has developed a couple really handy tools as well as a rather large "main" application all written in React. We wanted to try to somehow wrap these microservice frontends into the parent app.

There seems to be a litany of microservice frontend frameworks to choose from (Single-Spa, Luigi, etc.) but I've been having trouble understanding if any of them would take well to integration into a set of already existing frontend applications.

For reference all the applications already call back to Auth0 for identity management, so auth integration is at least *possible*.

Which microservice is best for integrating new frontend "features" into an existing monolith?

Comment: this article might help [link](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/7-different-ways-to-implement-micro-frontends-with-react-907b5e262230)

Comment: When you say "microservice", do you actually mean that or are you refering to microfrontends?

Comment: If it were me, I'd just separate each microservice by path and serve them via the web server of your choice.